# Highcharts, type: column, x-axis line is blocking some portion of the column which is making some values that are closer to 0 not visible

Tags: highcharts

````
 ```var yAxis = [{
            title: {
                text: 0
            },
            min:0,
            max:100,
            tickInterval: 50,
            labels: {
              formatter:function() {
                  return Math.ceil(Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value)) + '%';
              }
           }
        }];
xAxis: { gridLineWidth: 0,
                        labels:{
                          step:1,
                          useHTML:true,
                          maxStaggerLines: 0,
                        },
                    categories: data.labels
                }
```
````

So, the above are the xAxis and yAxis objects to my highChart, but the values closer to 0 such as 0.58 are rendered under the x-axis which makes it impossible to even identify the column. When I inspected the rectangle, I see the height="1" for such values but they are stuck under x-axis line. Please let me know if you find any solutions or any changes needed in the xAxis and yAxis.

Comment: You should add a runnable code snippet that reproduce the error you're referring to. It's hard to troubleshoot with example; especially when there's so many variables involve such as browser, device, display resolution, etc...

Comment: Could you reproduce the described issue with the sample data on some online editor which I could work on? Without it, it's hard to say what part of the code is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't recreate the same in jsFiddle to show you, I dont know why. jsFiddle looks good.

Comment: I am afraid that without the reproduction of the issue I am not able to help you.